solution of a PDE of 2 variables
I'm looking for complex valued functions $\phi(t,x)$ over $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ ($\phi^*$ is complex conjugate of $\phi$), which satisfy a PDE
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(\phi\dfrac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial t})-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\phi\dfrac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial x})=0 \ $$
(under some boundary conditions like $\ \phi(0,x)=f(x), \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(0,x)=g(x)$)
I tried to find the solutions by Fourier expansion.
Expanding as $\phi (t,x)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n(t)e^{i\pi nx} \   $ and inserting it to the PDE, I got
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n,m=-\infty}^{\infty}(\dot{c_n}(t)\dot{c _m}^*(t)+c_n(t)\ddot{c _m}^*(t))e^{i\pi (n-m)x}=\sum_{n,m=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n(t)c _m^*(t)\pi^2m(n-m)e^{i\pi(n-m)x}$$
(Here $\dfrac{\partial c_n}{\partial t }(t)=\dot{c_n}(t)$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2 c_n}{\partial t^2 }(t)=\ddot{c_n}(t)$)
However, I don't have any idea to get solution from this expression.
Are these solutions well known already? Or is there any good idea to get the solutions?

Is $\phi^*$ the complex conjugate of $\phi$?

@MOMO Yes, I forgot to remark it. I'll edit. Thanks.

I’m wondering, where is this PDE coming from? Is it simply something fun that you cooked up or is it coming from some kind of physics? Either way, it’s interesting and at least from the Fourier approach, I can’t see how this made the problem easier because now we have infinitely coupled nonlinear second-order ODEs.

Consider the compact notation for arbitrary derivative,
$$ \partial(\phi^*\phi)=\partial|\phi|^2=\phi\partial\phi^*+\phi^*\partial\phi $$
From this, your first equation can be transformed to
$$\partial_t \Bigg(\partial_t(|\phi|^2)-\phi^*\partial_t\phi\Bigg)-\partial_x \Bigg(\partial_x(|\phi|^2)-\phi^*\partial_x\phi\Bigg) = 0 $$
Expanding,
$$\boxed{\partial_t^2|\phi|^2-\partial_x^2|\phi|^2 - \partial_t(\phi^*\partial_t\phi) + \partial_x(\phi^*\partial_x\phi) = 0}  $$
Now consider $\phi = u+iv$
$$\partial(\phi^*\partial\phi) = \partial\Bigg((u-iv)(\partial u+i\partial v)\Bigg) = \partial\Bigg(u\partial u+v\partial v + i(u\partial v - v\partial u)\Bigg) \\
=(\partial u)^2+u\partial^2u+(\partial v)^2+v\partial^2v+i(\partial u \partial v+u\partial^2v-\partial v \partial u - v \partial^2u) \\ 
=(\partial u)^2+u\partial^2u+(\partial v)^2+v\partial^2v+i(u\partial^2v - v \partial^2u)$$
Now, looking at the purely real quantity $\partial^2|\phi|^2$, we have
$$\partial^2|\phi|^2 =\partial^2(u^2+v^2)=\partial(2u\partial u + 2v\partial v)=2(\partial u)^2+2u\partial^2u + 2(\partial v)^2+2v\partial^2v $$
Comparing with the above, we obtain
$$\boxed{\partial(\phi^*\partial\phi) = \frac{1}{2}\partial^2|\phi|^2+i(u\partial^2v - v \partial^2u)} $$
Now, consider the argument defined as $\theta=\text{arg}(\phi)=\text{arctan}(\frac{v}{u})$. Taking derivatives, we find
$$\partial\theta = \frac{1}{\frac{v^2}{u^2}+1}\Bigg(\frac{u\partial v - v \partial u}{u^2}\Bigg)=\frac{u\partial v - v \partial u}{u^2+v^2} = \frac{u\partial v - v \partial u}{|\phi|^2} $$
and
$$\partial|\phi|^2\partial\theta+|\phi|^2\partial^2\theta= \partial(u\partial v - v\partial u) = u\partial^2v-v\partial^2u$$
Comparison with the above boxed formula for $\partial(\phi^*\partial\phi)$ yields,
$$\boxed{\partial(\phi^*\partial\phi) = \frac{1}{2}\partial^2|\phi|^2 + i\Bigg(\partial|\phi|^2\partial\theta+|\phi|^2\partial^2\theta\Bigg)}$$
Finally substituting into the original boxed formula, we have the equation broken up into real and imaginary parts:
$$\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\partial_t^2|\phi|^2-\partial_x^2|\phi|^2\Bigg)+i\Bigg[|\phi|^2\Bigg(\partial^2_x\theta-\partial^2_t\theta\Bigg)+\partial_x |\phi|^2 \partial_x\theta -\partial_t |\phi|^2 \partial_t\theta \Bigg] = 0$$
The real part of this clearly gives the 1-D wave equation for the modulus like the other answer, but the imaginary part reveals an equation in the argument
$$\boxed{|\phi|^2\Bigg(\partial^2_x\theta-\partial^2_t\theta\Bigg)+\partial_x |\phi|^2 \partial_x\theta -\partial_t |\phi|^2 \partial_t\theta = 0}$$
which, given the solved 1-D wave equation from the other answer for the for the modulus, we can solve for $\theta$ knowing $|\phi|^2$.
Solving this still seems difficult as the solution for $|\phi|^2$ seems to make the equation for $\theta$ not separable. However, given $|\phi|^2$, this should be much easier to solve numerically instead of the original nonlinear PDE.

Would have been easier to just rewrite the function in polars $\phi = r(x, t) e^{i \theta(x, t)}$ to get
$$[r(r_{t} - i r \theta_{t})]{t} - [r(r{x} - i r \theta_{x})]{x} = 0$$
Separating into real and imaginary parts gives
\begin{align}
(r^{2}){tt} - (r^{2}){xx} &= 0 \
(r^{2} \theta{t}){t} - (r^{2} \theta{x})_{x} &= 0 \
\end{align}
where the first equation is just the equation for $\lvert \phi \rvert^{2}$ and can be used to remove terms in the second.

Thanks very much STL and Mathhew Cassell for equation of imaginary part! I completely forgot about imaginary part. Matthew Cassell's way is especially beautiful!! Both way give the same equation. I can try to find solutions with boundary conditions!

Note a full solution, but maybe a step in the right direction.
Start with the original PDE,
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(\phi\dfrac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial t})-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\phi\dfrac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial x})=0\label{1}\tag{1}$$
Conjugate it, you get:
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(\phi^*\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t})-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\phi^*\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})=0 \label{2}\tag{2}$$
Add $(1)$ and ($2)$, and you get
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(\phi\dfrac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial t} + \phi^*\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t})-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\phi\dfrac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial x} + \phi^*\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})=0$$
You can rewrite this as
$$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}(|\phi|^2)=\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(|\phi|^2)$$
We recognize the 1-dimensional wave equation. The boundary conditions are
$$\left \{ \begin{array}{ll}
|\phi(0, x)|^2 &= |f(x)|^2\\
\frac{\partial(|\phi|^2)}{\partial x}(0,x)&=\frac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial x}(0,x)\phi(0,x)+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(0,x)\phi(0,x)^*&=2 \Re (f^*(x)g(x))
\end{array}\right.$$
The solution that honors the boundary condition can be proven to be:
$$|\phi(t, x)|^2 = \frac{|f(x-t)|^2+|f(x+t)|^2}{2}+\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\Re(f^*(s)g(s))ds$$
That gives us the modulus.
For the argument, I tried subtracting \eqref{1} from \eqref{2}, but I'm not getting anywhere. I also tried looking for a solution of the separable form $\phi(t,x)=u(t)v(x)$, but I'm only getting to a form for $|u|^2$ and $|v|^2$, and the arguments are eluding me again.
EDIT: I was initially using the wrong boundary conditions. This is fixed, thanks to @particle-not good at english.

I think you should have used correct boundary conditions for $\mid \phi(t,x) \mid ^2$. Namely, $\mid \phi(0,x) \mid ^2 = \mid f(x)\mid^2$ and $\partial _x \mid\phi(x,0)\mid ^2=(\partial_x\phi ^)\phi+\phi ^\partial_x \phi = g^(x)f(x)+f^(x)g(x)$.

I really appreciate your clear answer and taking your time!
Thank you very much!

You're welcome! And thank you for spotting my mistake on the boundary condition.
